# Ionic FCM wasTapped always false

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Notification in Ionic framework with cordova fcm plugin. I want to open a state when user received push notification and tapped it. I am sending notification from Firebase console with params but It's always **data.wasTapped** false that's why it does not work.

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data) 
{
    if (data.wasTapped) {
        //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
        console.log("Tapped: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('state')) {
            $timeout(function(){
                $state.go(data.state);
            })

        }

    } 
    else 
    {
        //if user already opened app
        console.log("Not tapped: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}, function(msg) {
    console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to send `"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"` in your payload according to **cordova-plugin-fcm** (https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) but in the firebase console there is no scope to send this property. So you have to send it manually.

**Example**

```
//POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
//HEADER: Content-Type: application/json
//HEADER: Authorization: key=AIzaSy*******************
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",  //Any value
    "body":"Notification body",  //Any value
    "sound":"default", //If you want notification sound
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",  //Must be present for Android
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"  //White icon Android resource
  },
  "data":{
    "param1":"value1",  //Any data to be retrieved in the notification callback
    "param2":"value2"
  },
    "to":"/topics/topicExample", //Topic or single device
    "priority":"high", //If not set, notification won't be delivered on completely closed iOS app
    "restricted_package_name":"" //Optional. Set for application filtering
}
```

In the play store there is an android app I have found to send Firebase Notification. Hopefully this will help you to send Firebase Notification https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.learn24bd.fcm

Comment: when i added notification array in payload, i have received two notification

Comment: @Adam Thanks a lot, you've save my life :)

Comment: Hi there I also having same issue but after adding click_action params.. I am still not able to get data.wasTapped true..here is my php code https://gist.github.com/KishanIos007/e9064cd5e553ab507805dbcf0d713a18

Comment: After adding "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY" I can not get the console log showing data.wasTapped true but it's still not navigating.  I get this warning:

Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?

Comment: Hey...I'm able to get the data.wasTapped = true but I can't navigate after the app loads.  


this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
      if (data.wasTapped) {
        console.log("Received in background", data);
        console.log("Tapped: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log("Received in background", data.data());
        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/connections'));
      } else {
        console.log("Received in foreground", data.wasTapped);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/connections');
      }
    });